# How do I change the color of an external link?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a label with an eternal link in it, that I would like to change the color from the default blue to white.

```
label = QtWidgets.QLabel("<a href='https://example.com'> My Link </a>")
label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
```

I have tried three different methods and have found no further documentation to point me in the right direction, any guidance would be appreciated:

```
# None of these work
label.setStyleSheet("color: #ffffff")
label.setStyleSheet("a{color: #ffffff}")
label.setStyleSheet("QUrl{color: #ffffff}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the color you must use the style within the HTML:

```py
color = QtGui.QColor("white")
label = QtWidgets.QLabel(
    "<a href='https://example.com' style='color:{}'> My Link </a>".format(color.name())
)
```

Comment: Well that's going to be pain to put everywhere, but it does work, thank you!